# Powershell combine variables in echo

Tags: variables, powershell

I have a problem with my script.

I want to create a variable from 2 variables and then echo the result

```
$a = "server1"
$server_server1 = "Success"

echo ("`$server_$a")
```

The result of the echo should by **Success**

Thx in advance

Comment: You mean Success_server1 ?

Comment: The question is about working out which variable to read based on dynamically working out the variable name (based on another variable, named `$a`). At least that's what I based my answer on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Get-Variable` Cmdlet:

`(get-variable "server_$a").Value`

Which from your example, will give you `Success`.

See TechNet for more information on [Get-Variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849899.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

short way to accomplish same result:

```
iex  "`$server_$a"
```